# Pandas .apply Loc to Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I Have done some work with Pandas. Now I need to make the same on Pyspark and this task seem to be tricky !

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
def av_years(df,start,end):
return df.loc[df['year'].isin(range(start,end+1))]['B'].mean()
```

I then created a dataframe:

```
raw_data = {
    'year': [2010,2011,2012,2013],
    'B': [2,3,5,4],'startyear':[2012,2010,2011,2011],'endyear':
     [2012,2013,2013,2013]}
     df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
     df
```

This is my result:

```
    B   endyear startyear   year
    0   2   2012    2012    2010
    1   3   2013    2010    2011
    2   5   2013    2011    2012
    3   4   2013    2011    2013
```

The final step is t create a new column derived from the dataframe:

```
  df['av'] = df.apply(lambda row: av_years(df,row['startyear'], 
  row['endyear']), axis=1)
  df
```

My final result is :

```
 B  endyear startyear   year    av
 0  2   2012    2012    2010    5.0
 1  3   2013    2010    2011    3.5
 2  5   2013    2011    2012    4.0
 3  4   2013    2011    2013    4.0
```

I need to obtain the same table using PySpark ! some advice ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another method:

```
raw_data=sc.parallelize(['2\t2012\t2012\t2010\t5.0', \
                        '3\t2013\t2010\t2011\t3.5', \
                        '5\t2013\t2011\t2012\t4.0', \
                        '4\t2013\t2011\t2013\t4.0']).map(lambda x: x.split('\t'))\
                                                      .map(lambda x: (int(x[0]),int(x[1])\
                                                      ,int(x[2]),int(x[3]),float(x[4])))

raw_data_df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(rawdata,['B','endyear','startyear','year','av'])

raw_data_df.show()

+---+-------+---------+----+---+
|  B|endyear|startyear|year| av|
+---+-------+---------+----+---+
|  2|   2012|     2010|2010|5.0|
|  3|   2013|     2010|2011|3.5|
|  5|   2013|     2011|2012|4.0|
|  4|   2013|     2011|2013|4.0|
+---+-------+---------+----+---+
```

Let's say that you have the data in a csv file:

this is what it looks like in a filename *raw_data.csv*:

```
2,2012,2010,2010,5.0
3,2013,2010,2011,3.5
5,2013,2011,2012,4.0
4,2013,2011,2013,4.0
3,2008,2011,2011,4.0
5,2013,2019,2012,4.0
4,2005,2012,2016,4.0
4,2013,2013,2012,4.0
8,2018,2014,2018,4.0
5,2013,2014,2012,4.0
```

Import the necessary modules:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType, IntegerType, Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

Define the structure, and read the file:

```
rawdata_path = 'raw_data.csv'

rawdata_struct = artistdata_struct = StructType([StructField('B', IntegerType()), \
                                                 StructField('endyear', IntegerType()), \
                                                 StructField('startyear',IntegerType()), \
                                                 StructField('year',IntegerType()),\
                                                 StructField('av',DoubleType())])

rawdata= spark.read.csv(rawdata_path, sep = ',', schema = rawdata_struct)

rawdata.show()

+---+-------+---------+----+---+
|  B|endyear|startyear|year| av|
+---+-------+---------+----+---+
|  2|   2012|     2010|2010|5.0|
|  3|   2013|     2010|2011|3.5|
|  5|   2013|     2011|2012|4.0|
|  4|   2013|     2011|2013|4.0|
|  3|   2008|     2011|2011|4.0|
|  5|   2013|     2019|2012|4.0|
|  4|   2005|     2012|2016|4.0|
|  4|   2013|     2013|2012|4.0|
|  8|   2018|     2014|2018|4.0|
|  5|   2013|     2014|2012|4.0|
+---+-------+---------+----+---+
```

For additional information on Spark datatypes check this link

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/package-summary.html

Comment: I created the small dataframe to make it easy to undrestand ! In the reality I work with a huge dataframe. So how van I apply your method when I have a very big dataframe ?

Comment: Thank you! I amend my answer above. I assumed that you're data is in a **.csv** file. You can modify the separator to match what you have in your raw file.

Answer (score 1):

For every row in you dataframe you iterate through all the rows of the dataframes (complexity n²). This is equivalent to doing a self join. 
After filtering on the pairs of rows `(r1, r2)` that verify condition `r2.year.isin(range(r1.startyear, r1.endyear + 1))`, you can group by `startyear, endyear, year` to compute `mean(B)`.

NB: In Spark you can do the `join` and `filter` in one step.

First let's create the dataframe from your pandas `df`:

```py
data = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

For the self join we'll use aliases to avoid conflicts with column names:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
data_join = data.select("startyear", "endyear", "year").alias("left")\
    .join(
        data.select("B", "year").alias("right"), 
        psf.col("right.year").between(psf.col("left.startyear"), psf.col("left.endyear")))\
    .drop("right.year")

    +---------+-------+----+---+
    |startyear|endyear|year|  B|
    +---------+-------+----+---+
    |     2010|   2013|2011|  2|
    |     2010|   2013|2011|  3|
    |     2012|   2012|2010|  5|
    |     2010|   2013|2011|  5|
    |     2010|   2013|2011|  4|
    |     2011|   2013|2012|  3|
    |     2011|   2013|2013|  3|
    |     2011|   2013|2012|  5|
    |     2011|   2013|2012|  4|
    |     2011|   2013|2013|  5|
    |     2011|   2013|2013|  4|
    +---------+-------+----+---+
```

Now for the `groupBy`:

```py
data_join\
    .groupBy("startyear", "endyear", "year")\
    .agg(psf.avg("B").alias("av")).show()

    +---------+-------+----+---+
    |startyear|endyear|year| av|
    +---------+-------+----+---+
    |     2011|   2013|2013|4.0|
    |     2010|   2013|2011|3.5|
    |     2012|   2012|2010|5.0|
    |     2011|   2013|2012|4.0|
    +---------+-------+----+---+
```

Comment: Thank you Marie !

Comment: No problem Lizou :) Don't forget to mark your question as solved if it is indeed solved